# How to know which command settings of ImageMagick created a particular image

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, imagemagick-identify

Consider I have created an image `unknown.tiff` from a page of a PDF, named `doc.pdf`, where the exact command for conversion aren't known. The size of this image is ~ 1MB.

The exact command isn't known, but it is known that the changes are majorly on `depth` and `density`. (A subset of these two, would do too)

Now, the normal command pattern is:

```
convert -density 300 PDF.pdf[page-number] -depth 8 image.tiff
```

But this gives me a file of ~17 MB, which obviously isn't the one I am looking for. If I remove `depth`, then I get a file of ~34 MB, and when I remove both, I get a blurred image of 2 MB. I also removed `density` only, then too the results don't match (~37 MB).

Since the output size of the image `unknown.tiff` is so low, I've hypothesized that it might take less time to get produced.

Since the time of conversion is of great concern to me, I want to know the ways I can come to the exact command which produced `unknown.tiff`

Comment: Try `identify -verbose image.tiff` to see what you can see...

Comment: If the TIF was created with ImageMagick it may have used one of several compression methods. The command... `convert -list compress` ... will show you which methods are available in your version of IM. With most newer versions of IM, the compression method will be included in the output of the command... `convert unknown.tiff -verbose info:`. If that doesn't work, try what Mark said above... `identify -verbose unknown.tiff`.